# Segue to page view controller prevents to take data from array

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, segue

I have problem with app that I am creating. At this app I have added page view controller. When segue is directed to Page view controller. Pages can be scrolled but, it cannot take data from array, which is defined. But when segue is directed to the view controller, it takes data from array, but not scrolling pages, because it is not directed to page view controlled.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbAJN.png) - image

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47627912/edit) your question to include relevant code; how are you providing the array to the view controllers?

Comment: From where are you passing array from A to B Where pageViewController is present or Array is Declared in B Controller ? When Do PageController is initiated , Edit Question please